# Is it possible to write an operating system in C?

Tags: c, operating-systems

A while back I saw a comment on [a Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3073724/53543) that surprised me:

> No one can write an operating system in C. It is not possible. What
>   one can do is write an operating system in a C-based/C-like language
>   that adds/defines a considerable amount of non-standard capabilities
>   on top of C core.

Is it useful to define C so narrowly? People say Linux, or a GPU driver, or an embedded system was "written in C", not "written in C-with-some-extensions-to-accommodate-the-hardware."

Is it incorrect to do so?

Comment: People on SO just like to be really  technical for no good reason, 90% people will just say that linux is written in C

Comment: It is possible to write an OS using "only C" if you use some non-standard compiler features like naked functions, and inline assembly for a few things like `hlt`.

Comment: People wrote OS's in assembly before C came along (and even after).  You can write an OS in anything as long as it emits machine code and you can convince the bios that your OS is actually bootable. Supporting hardware is a bit of a different problem ;)

Comment: One of the issues you would run into is that C implementations use the call stack in ways that may not work for an interrupt service routine.  I remember back in the day, Turbo-C provided the `interrupt` keyword so that you could write interrupt service routines, and that if you worked at that low level, you sometimes had to resort to a bit of inline assembly.

Comment: I believe it is possible to write an operating system with a series of 8 donkeys that kick you in the head based on what sounds you make from your perhaps-abused mouth.

Comment: @ErikReppen I see no reason to drag Windows ME into this.

Comment: @GrandmasterB If it was ME they wouldn't be kicking you in the head.

Comment: I should maybe add that I *have* written an operating system in C. Or at least, I thought I had, until I read the quote above.

Answer (score 13):

The question is quite broad and as it stands the answer is yes. In fact, the answer is yes for most programming languages but there is a *catch*.

You need to translate your OS code into something that the machine understands. And it is the machine and its native language and your capability to translate from "your" language to the "native" language that would determine if you can write an operating system in your language or not.

### General Theory

Let's say a machine has a lever. And only two things are possible -when the lever is pushed down the machine shall pour coffee and when pulled up the machine shall stop pouring coffee. Now imagine my native language translator is a human who can read C code printed on a paper and decide whether to push the lever up or down. So, for example upon reading the following line our human "compiler-linker" will push the lever down.

```
printf("pour coffee"); //Support more similar syntax in later versions!
```

And on reading the following line our human "compiler-linker" will pull the lever up.

```
printf("stop pouring coffee"); //Support more similar syntax in later versions!
```

We have successfully written an operating system ***for this coffee machine*** entirely in C. For that matter, we can train our *compiler* to translate Java, C#, KSH, Perl, English, Slavik, Sanskrit etc… and "operate" the machine. Hence the term, Operating System.

Of course most modern computers are capable of doing something more complex than this. And hence the complexity of their [instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) goes beyond just a simple lever [state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_%28computer_science%29). These instruction sets will ultimately just put some transistors/magnets/LEDs etc. in some state and we humans will interpret that as a result.

The problem hence becomes one of manipulating this machine to achieve the states we want. And if your language (e.g., C) can be translated into that native instruction set *and* if you can use this bridge to make the machine do what you want then you shall have a successful operating system.

### Concrete Example

I am running an x86_64 system right now. This system does not know what C is. It does not know what OS X, Windows, or BSD are. It is ultimately running some x86_64 assembly code. That code was not written by humans (for most part). It was probably written by humans in C or C++ and translated into the assembly language. If I copy this compiled code on to my power PC machine it *will not* work. I need the original C/C++/whatever_language codebase and I need to translate that code to the power PC language. If I am trying something in C that is not translatable to power PC language then that feature *will not* work on the new operating system.

### What about devices?

The more devices you plug into the machine (e.g., a monitor, a mouse, a printer, an audio output etc.) the more code you will have to write for the bridges. That is what the drivers do. You can write a driver in C if you want. All you need is a way to translate C into the "instruction set" of that device. Usually, it is easier to just embed some code/circuit into the device that *reads* standard electrical signals and trick the core computer into generating those electrical signals using the standard instruction set and device buses (e.g., [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB)).

### What about bootstrapping?

Now of course, the operating system these days "ships" with the machine. And what people do is just install the code [compiled into the instruction set language of the machine] to some place where the machine can find it on its own. The trick is just to bootstrap the machine to find that code when booting it up. A [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) bootstrap example is below:

```
public final class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args_) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}

0000: cafe babe 0000 002e 001a 0a00 0600 0c09  ................
```

### What about… ?

Please see [Tanenbaum](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136006639) or ask another question.

Comment: Good answer, surprised that it doesn't have more up votes :-) Coffee machine example put a smile on my face.

Comment: Your code example `cout << "pour coffee"` is C++, not C!

Comment: I think this is the best answer, because it shows the entire issue/question is essentially just quibbling. It's more about what an OS is, rather than about capabilities of the C language.

Answer (score 12):

If you allow for the possibility of using device drivers (having a C interface) to communicate with the hardware, there's no reason you couldn't write an OS in ANSI C.  Anything you might need (like naked pointer) that's not present in ANSI C could be provided by the device driver.

I think the writer of that comment is being pedantic to make a point.  He's saying that you can't capture every possible thing that you might need to do in an operating system in the ANSI C language.  I'm not sure I agree; ANSI C is a Turing-complete language, and has many low-level constructs including bit twiddling.

In any case, you quoted him out of context.  Look at one of the additional comments further down in the thread:

> ...you're making it sound more drastic than it is. A small amount of
>   assembly language (inline or in separate files) and a good linker are
>   really all you need on most architectures. Other non-standard stuff
>   that kernels use (like fiddling with output sections, packing,
>   alignment, branch-prediction hints, crazy pointer arithmetic,
>   undefined union behaviour) is for **optimisation.**

Comment: My intention isn't to snipe at a particular commenter, but to suss out the boundaries of when one can say "X was written in C" and when you really need to say "X was written in a C-like language."

Comment: It's English.  You were expecting a hard and fast rule?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to be able set specific registers and call IRQs to write drivers? I haven't done device drivers for modern PCI bus stuff.

Comment: @Martin Beckett - I've written embedded systems that used IRQs and specific hardware registers, and that was done in C (mid-90s). As far as I remember there were some extensions involved, but it wasn't a big deal - placing variables at specific addresses, probably a few "intrinsics".

Comment: @steve314 But if you use nonstandard intrinsically and the technically undefined behavior of poking variables to (uint) addresses, are you still working in C? The person quoted would seem to think not.

Comment: Intinsics not intrinsically. Dammit, autocorrect.

Comment: @Crashworks - doing stuff that's not part of the standard is part of the "standard" for C. Providing extensions is explicitly allowed and expected, and the standard explicitly defines a lot as platform-defined behavior. In fact C was initially developed between 1969 and 1973 and was in widespread use for a long time before the first ANSI standard in 1989. And as stated elsewhere, the person quoted would seem to think not for the purposes of the specific argument being made - what that person says elsewhere shows a more balanced view.

Comment: @Crashworks - BTW - "poking" suggest a poke-style command, using terminology borrowed from BASIC. I meant declaring that a particular variable is mapped to a particular address, so every read/write of that variable is a read/write of that address. There was no special intrinsic or library call for accessing device registers - I'm not even sure that there was non-standard syntax now.

Comment: -1 because Turing-completeness has literally nothing to do with whether a language can be used for this task (general consensus seems to be that C is *not* Turing-complete, but that's even more irrelevant). Being able to emit machine code that can be read by the metal is the only thing.

Comment: @Leushenko: Your comment is both wrong and largely irrelevant.  Turing-completeness is a minor point in my answer, but yes, you need a *real* programming language to do this  (HTML is not going to get it done). Yours is the only downvote, BTW.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it incorrect to do so?

It is not "incorrect" to define C that way ... in a particular context.

> My intention isn't to snipe at a particular commenter, but to suss out the boundaries of when one can say "X was written in C" and when you really need to say "X was written in a C-like language."

One can say what one likes!  There are no IT terminology laws that say what words mean.

The guy is making a (somewhat pedantic) point by equating "C" with the language that is strictly defined by the ANSI C standards.  But that's OK.  We *know* what he *means*.

And the flips-side is that the rest of us can use "C" to mean practical implementations of the C language ... if we want to.

Answer (score 3):

I think that whoever wrote that comment doesn't know what he's talking about because the reason behind C's creation was to write Unix (*one* of the best operating systems of all time) I'm not saying it's the best language to write an operating system with because many things have changed since the creation of Unix, and now there are many languages that are better than C when it comes to writing an operating system , but it's far from impossible to write an OS with C.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix

Answer (score 3):

There is one big problem with writing a kernel *purely* in a high level language: No high level language in existence allows you access to all the CPU instructions that an OS has to use.

Take for example the X86 architecture: It implements virtual memory by providing a single special purpose register which points to a tree of page tables. Now, a kernel that needs to set up the virtual address space for a process needs to do two things: 1. build the tree of page tables, and 2. load a pointer to the root of that tree into the special purpose register. However, *that special purpose register is inaccessible from C*. Step 1 can be done in C, step 2 can't. - The set of instructions that can come out of a C compiler is a true subset of the available CPU instructions, and that subset lacks all those special purpose instructions that are required to manipulate the processing mode of the CPU itself.

That is why every kernel in existence has to include some amount of assembler code. Of course, kernel programmers try to keep the amount of assembler code as low as possible, writing the bulk of the kernel in a high level language like C. This bulk of code is the reason why people say "Linux is written in C", because 99% of the Linux kernel is indeed C code. But C alone cannot do the trick.

Comment: "There is one big problem with writing a kernel purely in a high level language: No high level language in existence allows you access to all the CPU instructions that an OS has to use." 1) can you back that claim up? 2) in any case, it would the compiler, not the high level language which decides what Instructions are used, so blame it on a compiler, not a language

Comment: @Mawg No, I have to blame it on the language: It is the language that does not provide constructs that could be compiled to a load of the cr3 register to change the virtual address space. Compilers cannot use this register for normal purposes, so for the compiler to be able to emit such instructions, you require special language constructs. Intrinsic functions would suffice, but they must be built into the language. As to whether there are languages allowing this: Obviously I don't know all languages out there, but I don't know any that could manipulate the virtual address space.